# like to liked resume after reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm creating a website where user can "like" certain posts. I want to change "like" to "liked" when it is clicked. The following code achieve this goal. The problem is, after I refresh the page, "liked" resume into "like". Can someone tell me how to permanently change "like" to "liked"? Is it possible to get it done in JavaScript? I don't want to run a sql statement in every posts to check whether a particular user clicked "like" for that post because those statements may slow the website.

Here is my php code:

```
echo"<a href="#" class="likes" id="$postid" >like</a>";
```

here is my javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".likes").click(function(){
            var postid = $(this).attr("id");
            if (document.getElementById(postid).innerHTML=="like")
                document.getElementById(postid).innerHTML="liked";
            else
                document.getElementById(postid).innerHTML="like";
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
to achieve your goal., you have to save it to the database,
on your function,
 $(".likes").click(function(){
            var postid = $(this).attr("id");
            var like = 0;
            if (document.getElementById(postid).innerHTML=="like")
                document.getElementById(postid).innerHTML="liked";
                 like = 1;
            else
                document.getElementById(postid).innerHTML="like";
                 like = 0;

             $.ajax{
                     type: POST
                     data: { 'like': like, 'postid': id}
                     url: url to save your query
                     ----------etc 
             }

});

create an ajax post and save it to your database,
that's the only way you it wont disappear,
```

Comment: do you mean that I have to keep track of which user has "like" which posts? Depending on the user, a post can either appears to have a "like" button or a "liked " button, so I'm wondering if I have to send userid to the database as well.

Comment: yes, you have to keep track of users that liked a post, to avoid abuse on the like button and opening up different browsers to like the same post over and over ,

Comment: yes you have to save the userid of the users who liked the post,  just like in facebook, where in we can see who liked a certain post,